# Rails rabl json format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rabl

I'm displaying data from my db in json format using rabl to parse it for android...
My json looks like so:

```
[
   {
      "bank":{
         "central_office_address":"ololo",
         "license":"12312312",
         "location_id":3,
         "name":"Pbank",
         "tax_number":"12312312",
         "year_of_foundation":1987
      }
   },
   {
      "bank":{
         "central_office_address":"sdfsdf sdf",
         "license":"321312",
         "location_id":3,
         "name":"Bbank",
         "tax_number":"321321",
         "year_of_foundation":1999
      }
   }
]
```

I need my json in a format like:

```
{
    "contacts": [
        {
                "id": "c200",
                "name": "Ravi Tamada",
                "email": "ravi@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c201",
                "name": "Johnny Depp",
                "email": "johnny_depp@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        }
    ]
}
```

Such data is normally parsed in java....

My rabl view:

```
object @banks

attributes :central_office_address, :license, :location_id, :name, :tax_number, :year_of_foundation
```

How do I change its output to match the second example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done in such way:

```
collection @banks, :root => "bank", :object_root => false
attributes :central_office_address, :license, :location_id, :name, :tax_number, :year_of_foundation
```

maybe it is bad idea?

Comment: From rolled-back edit comment: It has to be "banks", not "bank" in order to match his desired format.